# Set dataclass variable to double the default value

Tags: python, default-value, python-dataclasses

This is probably too much of a perfectionist question but.. I'd like to instantiate a dataclass with double the default value. So that if I change the default value, instantiating it will provide double the usual default. I'm hoping there is a better way to do this than simply reading and updating the values.

Here is a simple example to explain what I want:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Value:
    variable1: int = 1
    variable2: int = 2
    variable3: int = 3    

value = Value()
doubled_value = Value() {* 2 for all}

print(value.variable1)
print(value.variable2)
print(value.variable3)

print(doubled_value.variable1)
print(doubled_value.variable2)
print(doubled_value.variable3)

>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3

>>> 2
>>> 4
>>> 6
```

This works but is hard to understand and ugly:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Value:
    variable1: int = 1
    variable2: int = 2
    variable3: int = 3    

value = Value()
doubled_value = Value()

for i, var in enumerate(doubled_value.__dataclass_fields__.items()):
    doubled_value.__setattr__(var[0], var[1].default*2)

print(value.variable1)
print(value.variable2)
print(value.variable3)

print(doubled_value.variable1)
print(doubled_value.variable2)
print(doubled_value.variable3)

>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3

>>> 2
>>> 4
>>> 6
```

To be clear, I want it to work regardless of default value so `doubled_value = Value(2, 4, 6)` won't work

Thank you for any help.
This is my first post on stack overflow so please let me know if I've made any mistakes.

Comment: `doubled_value = Value() {* 2 for all}` is invalid python. How do you distinguish between when you want the default values and when doubled - in both cases you use the default values. Why not change the default values

Comment: So just to confirm, if instance is instantiated and non-defaults are specified, ex. like `Value(2, 4, 6)`, do you also want all attributes doubled, like `v1=4, v2=8, v3=12`?

Comment: `doubled_value = Value(2, 4, 6)` **won't** work, I assume you meant to say **will** work, right? So that the doubling does work in this case.

Comment: Follow-up question, it’s not clear from post above, but do you *really* need to instantiate class with original values (not multiplied)? I assume no, right? That you only need to create class object with values doubled, nothing apart from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class Value:
    variable1: int = 1
    variable2: int = 2
    variable3: int = 3    

    @classmethod
    def times(cls, times=2):
        return cls(*(f.default * times for f in fields(cls)))

value = Value()
doubled_value = Value.times()
tripled_value = Value.times(3)
```

[`fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) allows you to obtain a list of fields and their `default` values, which I'm simply multiplying in a generator expression, which is unpacked to arguments to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **mul** method to make multiply operations with this class. For example the code can be:

```
class Value:
    variable1: int = 1
    variable2: int = 2
    variable3: int = 3
    
    def __mul__(self, value):
        # you can change this method to create a new object with the new values if you prefer
        self.variable1 *= value
        self.variable2 *= value
        self.variable3 *= value

value = Value()
value*2 # all the variables will be multiplied by 2
print(value.variable1,value.variable2,value.variable3) # prints 2 4 6
```